# Please tell me if the office takes an article or not in the below sentence?

Tags: articles

**Do you have office today?** -> Is this sentence grammatically correct or not? I believe Office would take an article over here but google translate is saying that in this sentence office wouldn't take an article.

Thank You!

Comment: You should explain what you're trying to say. Neither "do you have office today" nor "do you have an office today" are idiomatic.

Comment: "office" usually means a room in which you do work, especially paperwork or business meetings.  Some people have an office to work in.  But it would be very odd to ask if someone has an office *today*.  Do you see why that is strange?  There are other meanings, such as a short way saying "The Microsoft Office suite of Word/Excel/Powerpoint"  or "an official position in government,  So what to *you* mean?

Comment: It sounds like it might be jargon specific to a company or institution, in which case you'll just have to copy other people or find another way of expressing it.

Comment: I'd guess the intended meaning is "Are you working today", trying to use "office" to mean "the activity of attending the office", in the same way as you might say "Do you have school today?" But I've never heard an English speaker use "office" in that way.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to use 'office' in the same way that we might use 'work' or 'school'.

For example:

- Do you have work today?
- Do you have school today?

Although you may have noticed that some people do say "*I'm in the office*" to mean they are *in work*, what you are suggesting is not idiomatic. We cannot use 'office' without an article in this kind of context. 'Work' and 'school' can be *abstract nouns* - intangible things that you cannot count or touch. Although 'office' does have an abstract use, when it refers to *a position of authority*, the kind of office you work in is a physical place.